# Moved off of React SPA on S3/Cloudfront, but users' browsers are still showing old, cached SPA

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

DNS Is being handled via Route53. Previously, had a React SPA deployed on AWS S3 (with Cloudfront dist + SSL). Moved off of that to a SSR NextJS app on ElasticBeanstalk, but even after changing the A records and invalidating CF, some users are still reporting their browser is using the old S3 SPA. Only fix is for them to manually clear their cache for the site.

*Asking each random user that's cached my site to manually refresh their cache for the page doesn't seem like a good solution ;)*

**Here's what I've done thus far:**

- Updated Route53 (A record) to point to the EB server (this is working as intended),
- Tried disabling the associated CF distribution,
- When that didn't work, I removed the files in S3 and invalidated the CF dist,
- **EDIT:** After deleting the CF dist completely, users are able to go to the new site - but only after hard-refreshing a half-dozen times. I still feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this requiring little/no user know-how.

> All of my CSS & JS files had version numbers appended to help with cache-busting. Users report that they see the HTML structure of the page, but the versioned JS & CSS 404 for them (as they should, since the files no longer exist).

I would have thought this would be enough to have the browser swap update its cache - but apparently not. Only solution so far has been for affected users to manually clear their cache.

More than happy to offer more details if needed, any thoughts/input is super appreciated!

Comment: If clearing the cache solves the problem, then it can only really be browser caching.  Did you have aggressive `Cache-Control` settings on the old site's main page (which wouldn't have had the same cache-busting since it's the main page of the site)?

Comment: Did you invalidate the cache in Cloudfront? They charge you for this but this is how you would clear the cache.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Nope, had issues in the past with cache-busting on CF so all of my relevant headers/meta were set to super low values.

Comment: @JackMarchetti Yeah, did that a few times; even removed everything from S3 and then invalidated - same result.

So far, only thing that has worked at all was disabling then completely deleting the distribution - but it still requires the user to manually refresh multiple times. 

Think I could be content with a single refresh, most of our target audience are savvy enough to give that a go - but multiple refreshes hurts a bit, I think.

Comment: *If* requests were somehow still arriving at CloudFront, they would not have been served if the distribution was disabled... but anything that was served should have been logged.  Deleting it should not have been necessary, and even that doesn't explain the "multiple refreshes."  Something else is/was happening, because none of this is normal/expected.  HTTP headers from browser developer tools would have been helpful, but if only some end-users were experiencing this then it wouldn't really be reasonable to try to get an end user to inspect those.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That was my thought - didn't have a chance to get access to the headers the affected users reported (I couldn't duplicate and it's maybe 1 out of 8-10 users being affected). I do know I've had periodic issues in the past with cache busting on S3/Cloudfront with React, which was certainly one of the reasons we wanted to move off of it.


Thanks for the help/thoughts - if I continue getting reports and get a hold of the headers from someone, will update here; otherwise will just continue and hope for the best. This seems like a weird, unique circumstance.